# copy and insert shapes with series increase

Tags: excel, vba

I tried doing it using .Addshape but i feel its not best way to do it.I feel Copy and Paste with increase in series is best way to do it but i could not find a way of doing as i am starter in VBA

.

```
Private Sub Click()

    Dim i, iLeft, iTop, iWidth, iheight As Integer
    Dim c, j As Range

    Set j = Range("A4")
    Set c = Range("D7:D8")

    iLeft = c.Left + (c.Width / 4)
    iTop = c.Top
    iWidth = c.Width / 2
    iheight = c.Height

    For i = 1 To j

        Dim ovalShape As Shape
        Set ovalShape = Sheet1.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, iLeft, iTop, iWidth, iheight)

        With ovalShape
            ovalShape.ShapeStyle = msoLineStylePreset7
            ovalShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text = i
        End With

        iLeft = iLeft + 145
        DoEvents
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Due to this "iLeft = iLeft + 145" If i change the column width the shapes will not be on expected column and space.So i wanted if there is a way to copy D Column Range with shape and then paste offsetting 2 column with increase in series i.e either 1,2,3 or A,B,C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your only issue is to change:

```
For i = 1 To j
```

to:

```
For i = 1 To j.Value
```

since `j` has been dimmed and Set as a `Range` object

But since you use that range only to retrieve its value at the beginning, then it's best to:

```
dim j As Long
…. 
j = Range("A4").Value
```

Other than that, you could adopt explicit variables dimming along with `Option Explicit` statement:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Click()

    Dim i As Long, iLeft As Long, iTop As Long, iWidth As Long, iHeight As Long, j As Long
    Dim c As Range

    j = Range("A4").Value
    Set c = Range("D7:D8")

    iLeft = c.Left + (c.Width / 4)
    iTop = c.Top
    iWidth = c.Width / 2
    iHeight = c.Height

    With Sheet1 ' reference 'Sheet1' worksheet
        For i = 1 To j

            With .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, iLeft, iTop, iWidth, iHeight) ' reference referenced sheet newly added shape
                .ShapeStyle = msoLineStylePreset7
                .TextFrame.Characters.Text = i
            End With
            DoEvents
            With c.Offset(, 3 * i)
                iWidth = .Width / 2
                iLeft = .Left + .Width / 4
            End With
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

As you see I:

1) changed all `Integer` types to `Long`

because in VBA `Integer`s ranges to some +/-32k while `Long`s reach some +/-2billions, and it's good practice to adopt this latter type not to incurr in any overflow error when, for instance, looping through rows that can reach up to 1 million or so

2) explicitly declared all variables

since in VBA all unexplicitly declared variables are assumed as of `Variant` type

so that:

```
Dim i, iLeft, iTop, iWidth, iheight As Integer
Dim c, j As Range
```

would be read as:

```
Dim i As Variant, iLeft As Variant, iTop As Variant, iWidth As Variant, iheight As Integer
Dim c As Variant, j As Range
```

while you want them as:

```
Dim i As Long, iLeft As Long, iTop As Long, iWidth As Long, iheight As Long
Dim c As Range, j As Range
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the tip!! But is there a way where i can copy and paste the column along with predefined shape(i.e on D column) and paste with increase in series i.e 1,2,3 and A,B,C.The problem with my code is that if i change column width the shapes will not be on expected place i.e on center.

Comment: You are welcome. And see edited code to keep adding shapes every other third column regardless of their actual width